# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'message' in value "${message}"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config-server, spring-cloud-config-client

i have problem when i try to GET data spring cloud config client to spring cloud confing server. my config in the server is running, but i coundlt get the data from my client

This is my config client properties in the application.properties

```
spring.application.name=service-transfer
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8081/
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
spring.cloud.config.enabled=true
```

this is my config server in the application.properties

```
spring.application.name=Spring-Cloud-Config-Server
server.port=8081
spring.cloud.config.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/mendochandra/spring-cloud-config.git
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main
```

and this is my controller to get message in the config server
@RestController
public class ServiceController {

```
    @Value("${message}")
    private String myKey;

    @GetMapping
    public String prop(){
        return "Property =" + myKey ;
    }

}


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'message' in value "${message}"
```

this is dendencies i used

```
dependencies {


implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'


implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server'
//  implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
//  compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
//  runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
//  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client'
//  implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-parent:2020.0.1'
```

}

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Comment: the cause is  that you may  in a incorrect usage with spring config center , try to read the spring offical  reference

Comment: sorry for post images of text, its my first time ask in the stack overflow, but i didnt understand to share my code in the text

Comment: Now you can [edit] your question and fix that!

Comment: sorry, i already edit my question

Answer (score 0):

you need the "message" property in the properties file

Comment: hi thank you for answer my problem, in my properties files, i already declare message in my property, but it has the same problem, he cant read message in the value annotation. even in my run log, it didnt fetch data from config server, can u help with me?

Answer (score 0):

try to add 'message = something' into properties file

Comment: hi thank you for answer me, but i already add it but the value of annotation not read at all